# How can I see if Windows is getting RADVD advertisements?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, ipv6

I'm troubleshooting my home network setup and am looking for a way to see if windows is receiving radvd advertisements on a certain interface because I believe that my router isn't sending on WLAN.

Is there any command or program which can show me when they're received?

If there's no way to do in in windows, a GNU/Linux program could help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Wireshark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) can show received network traffic on both Windows and Linux. Enter `icmpv6` to the "Filter" box.